# Child component is rendering before data comes back from post request causes blank screen

Tags: reactjs

After making post request the data post to the database and comes back in the response but props doesn't get passed down in time causing a undefined error in props resulting in blank screen. The ApiManager is a generic crud controller to handle request. I want to know should I use componentWillReceiveProps componentDidUpdate or shouldComponentUpdate and what are generally the best practices for child components updating appropriately

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ZoneData from './ZoneData'
import { ApiManager }  from '../utils'

class Zones extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      zone:{
        name:'',
        zipcode: ''
      },
      list: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    ApiManager.get('http://localhost:3033/api/zone', null, (err, response) => {
      if(err){
        console.log(err)
        return
      }
      console.log(response)
      this.setState({
        list: response.results
      })
    })
  }

  updateZone (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('updateZone: '+event.target.id+'=='+event.target.value)
    let updateZone = Object.assign({}, this.state.zone)
    updateZone[event.target.id] = event.target.value
    this.setState({
      zone: updateZone
    })
  }

  addZone () {
    let updatedZone = Object.assign({}, this.state.zone)
    ApiManager.post('http://localhost:3033/api/zone', updatedZone, (err, response) => {
      if(err){
        alert('ERROR '+err.message)
        return
      }
      console.log("Post created: "+JSON.stringify(response))
      let zoneList = Object.assign([], this.state.list)
      zoneList.push(response.result)
        this.setState({
            list: zoneList
        })          
    })
  }

  render(){
    const listItems = this.state.list.map((zone, i) => {
      return <li className="list-group-item"  key={i}><ZoneData currentZone={zone}/></li>
    })
    return (
      <div className="position-sticky">
      <ul className="list-group">
        {listItems}
      </ul>
        <input id='name' onChange={this.updateZone.bind(this)} className='form-control' placeholder="name"/>
        <input id='zipcode' onChange={this.updateZone.bind(this)} className='form-control' placeholder="zipcode"/>
        <button onClick={this.addZone.bind(this)} className='btn btn-primary'>Add Zone</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Zones
```

child component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const ZoneData = (props) => {
 return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2><a href="#">{props.currentZone.name}</a></h2>
      <span>{props.currentZone.zipcode}</span><br/>
      <span>{props.currentZone.numPosts}</span>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ZoneData
```

child component props.currentZone.name comes back as undefined after making post request and the screen turns blank with out updating the child components props.
when I refresh the the new data that was posted to the database is there

Comment: Add a `console.log(this.state)` and check if the state gets updated after you have clicked **Add Zone** button.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should add some variable like isListReady to check if list is ready for showing and everything will be ok.

```
render(){
    const {list} = this.state;
    const isListReady = list && list.length; 

    const listItems = isListReady && list.map((zone, i) => {
      return <li className="list-group-item"  key={i}><ZoneData currentZone={zone}/></li>
    })

    return (
      <div className="position-sticky">
      <ul className="list-group">
        {isListReady && listItems}
      </ul>
        <input id='name' onChange={this.updateZone.bind(this)} className='form-control' placeholder="name"/>
        <input id='zipcode' onChange={this.updateZone.bind(this)} className='form-control' placeholder="zipcode"/>
        <button onClick={this.addZone.bind(this)} className='btn btn-primary'>Add Zone</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the blank screen because you should use `componentWillMount()` instead of `componentDidMount()`. `componentDidMount()` makes an api call after the component has rendered. And I think you also need to do conditional rendering too, for `listItems`. Something like this:

```
render(){
    const listItems = this.state.list.map((zone, i) => {
      return <li className="list-group-item"  key={i}><ZoneData currentZone={zone}/></li>
    })
    return (
      <div className="position-sticky">
      <ul className="list-group">
        {this.state.isListAvailable && listItems}
      </ul>
        {// other code}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

you can set `isListAvailable` to `true` when you have the list and the data.

Comment: still can not get this to work ..... feels like i'm having brain freeze...I know this solution is obvious....just having a moment here....

Comment: I keep getting Cannot read property 'name' of undefined and a blank screen everything else is working great.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its vacation time but it was a typo on response.result should have been response.results